# Submitting a JSF2 form does not reload the collection on the same page

Tags: jsf-2, mojarra

JSF 2.0 (mojarra) application. I have a very trivial form for adding an item

```
<h:form>
    #{msg['add custom title']}:<br />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>#{msg['heaading']}:</td>
            <td><h:inputText value="#{titlesBean.title.heading}"></h:inputText></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                          ...
        </tr>
    </table>
    <h:commandButton action="#{titlesBean.addTitle}" value="#{msg['g.save']}" />
</h:form>
```

And then on the same page I have a list of all the items already added:

```
<h:dataTable id="manualTitlesForm" value="#{titlesBean.manualTitles}" var="title" border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">#{msg['heaading']}</f:facet>
        #{title.heading}
    </h:column>
            ...
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">#{msg['actions']}</f:facet>
        <h:form>
            <h:commandButton action="#{titlesBean.editManualTitle(title)}" value="#{msg['g.edit']}" />
            <h:commandButton action="#{titlesBean.deleteManualTitle(title.id)}" value="#{msg['g.delete']}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

The code in the bean code is super simple:

```
@Controller
@Scope(Scopes.REQUEST)
public class TitlesBean {

    private List<JTitle> manualTitles;


    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        this.manualTitles = titlesManager.getManualTitles();
    }

    public String addTitle() {
        title.setCreated(new Date());
        title.setManual(true);
        try {
            titlesManager.addTitle(title);
            title = new JTitle();// this is added, delete from the variable. only if no exception though !!!
            UserMessagesBean.addMessage("saved");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            UserMessagesBean.setValidationException(e.getMessage());//different exception added
        }
        return null;
    }

    public List<JTitle> getManualTitles() {
        return manualTitles;
    }
    }
```

Now the problem is that `getManualTitles()` is called as many times as the number of titles I have, which causes for example 12 calls to the DB, instead of one. Why is this happening is beyond my understanding. I can fix this with caching the manual titles in the bean. This is not my main problem.

The problem is that `addTitle()` is called AFTER `getManualTitles()`. In fact `getManualTitles()` is called for example 10 times, then `addTitle()`, then two more times the `getManualTitles()` method. This makes me think that this is some kind of parallel execution which causes my page to show only the 12 old records instead of 13. I have to reload the page, then 13 is shown.

**UPDATED: now caches the list.** Problem still not solved.

WHY? How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update backing bean in datatable from h:commandButton and JPA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221758/update-backing-bean-in-datatable-from-hcommandbutton-and-jpa)

Comment: This answers the question of multiple calls to the database, but how does that solve my main problem?

Comment: This is covered by the code example in the answer as well.

Comment: I have especially for this question updated my code with @PostConstruct. This does not solve my reload problem without redirect.

Comment: I don't see the thing from the other example that should fix my problem with not seeing up-to-date data.

Comment: That's definitely not a JSF problem. Perhaps you're using JPA and you simply didn't merge the entities into the current persistence context (which is by default namely threadlocal and in case of a webapplication thus requestbased).

Comment: This is a problem my colleagues and I experienced more than once in different projects. It really doesn't make sense to be a JSF problem, but I have it nonetheless and I need a solution.

Answer (score -1):

This is a quick fix, but not a real solution. Redirect the result of `addTitle()`:

Add the following to `addTitle()`:

```
    ...
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
        .redirect("manualTitles.jsf");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that you're doing business job in a getter method! See also the duplicate link.

Comment: Ok, ignore that part, consider it solved, will that solve my other issue?