# JSF update datatable using AJAX after dialog edit of record which was fully populated using actionListener

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have a PrimeFaces datatable with edit buttons on each row that open a Primefaces dynamic dialog but to overcome LazyLoad exception when the dialog renders I use `actionListener` to requery the database and fully populate `selectedItem`.

After updating the record in the dialog the datable does not get refreshed. I know I have the `update=` correct, and realize the issue is because the object I am updating is not the actual object referenced in the table, but a new fully loaded object instantiated in the actionListener.

My fix is to use `indexOf` and re-set that value in the list with the fully loaded `selectedItem` Is this the correct approach or is this a hack?  It probably could backfire if the Object's equals is not coded correctly.

```
public void update() {     
   dataService.update(selectedItem);
   listOfItems.set(listOfItems.indexOf(selectedItem), selectedItem); <-Typically done?
}
```

---

Here are more details to my approach

```
<h:form id="formId">
<p:dataTable id="dataTableId" value="#{dataManagerView.listOfItems}" var="item">

<p:column headerText="Action">
   <p:commandButton oncomplete="PF('editDialogWv').show()" update=":outlookDialogId" 
          actionListener="#{dataManagerView.loadDataViewDetails(item)}" >
       <ui:remove>Cannot do just this due to LazyLoad Exception
          <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{dataManagerView.selectedItem}" />
       </ui:remove>
   </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

```
public void loadDataViewDetails(Item item) {
    // Called from actionListener
    selectedItem = dataService.retrieveFullById(item.getId());
}
```

```
<p:dialog id="outlookDialogId" dynamic="true" widgetVar="outlookDialogWv" >
   <h:form id="outlookFormId">
         bunch of form input boxes
     <p:commandButton update="formId:dataTableId" action="#{dataManagerView.update()}">
   </p:commandButton>
   </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

```
public void update() {
   dataService.update(selectedItem); //The selected item only refreshes in table if I manually refresh browser 
}
```

This works but is it the right approach?

```
public void update() {
   dataService.update(selectedItem);
   listOfItems.set(listOfItems.indexOf(selectedItem), selectedItem);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *This works but is it the right approach?*

That's okay. Provided that the `equals()` method only checks the technical equality (e.g. generated key) instead of the natural equality (the entire object, i.e. all properties). Else the changes you made on the selected item might cause the `equals()` to return `false`. More safe would be:

```
public void loadDataViewDetails(Item item) {
    originalSelectedItem = item;
    selectedItem = dataService.retrieveFullById(item.getId());
}
public void update() {     
   dataService.update(selectedItem);
   listOfItems.set(listOfItems.indexOf(originalSelectedItem), selectedItem);
}
```

But usually you'd just reload the entire list/page from the service in order to ensure that all other items also have the latest changes reflected, in case it's being edited by someone else in the meanwhile. E.g.

```java
public void update() {     
   dataService.update(selectedItem);
   listOfItems = dataService.getListOfItems();
}
```

#### See also:

- [Right way to implement equals contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181339/right-way-to-implement-equals-contract/)
- [Changes not reflected in JPA entities after updating in h:dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221758/changes-not-reflected-in-jpa-entities-after-updating-in-hdatatable/7230169#7230169)

Comment: Good point on reloading entire list, preferable with pagination, to ensure it is most current.  I always took the stance of not reloading lists assuming it was wasteful since I already had it in memory and db calls were expensive.  But it sure would make it things much easier to just reload and start with fresh state.